# Decoding html entities issue

Tags: php, character-encoding

I have the following line of text that I need to display

```
<ul><li>Complementary to cleansing with HY-ÖL®<li>Especially for irritated and sensitive skin<li>Noticeably calms and relaxes the skin</ul>
```

if I do the following

```
html_entity_decode('<ul><li>Complementary to cleansing with HY-ÖL®<li>Especially for irritated and sensitive skin<li>Noticeably calms and relaxes the skin</ul>');
```

the text comes ou the following way

```
* Complementary to cleansing with HY-�L�
* Especially for irritated and sensitive skin
* Noticeably calms and relaxes the skin
```

the problem is that it tries to encode the HY-ÖL® aswell and then it ends up like this HY-�L�

Confused here, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your header-encoding to see that you're sending the right encoding.

Example for utf-8 encoding.

`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify the character encoding you want the output in:

```
html_entity_decode('…', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')
```

Otherwise [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode) assumes ISO 8859-1 as default.

Comment: Now I get the following Warning: cannot yet handle MBCS in html_entity_decode()!

Comment: @Roland: Are you still using PHP 4? You should update/upgrade your PHP. See http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=25670

Comment: @Gumbo Yep, php 4 is install on the server

Comment: @Gumbo Thanx for this solution unfortunately I'm not the server admin, so no way for me to upgrade. xintron's solution solved my problem at the end. 1up for you

Comment: @Roland: What? That can’t be. Or are you using ISO 8859-1 now?

Comment: @Gumbo - I did not manage to get rid of the error, encoding is ASCii, html_entity_decode did not recognise ASCii

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the page's encoding type to `utf-8` eg:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```